# Firebase .indexOn on nested items

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying now for too long to get my index right, but to no luck till now..

My database structure is:

```
(app name)
  + searches 
    + -Kw_Eyk6zbCcFklO119u (firebase random key) 
      + FlightOffers 
        + c6aa0d29-31b7-4113-81ab-8de2e4ee877e (firebase random key)
          + PricingOptions 
            + 0 
              + Price
```

In React, I use the following code:

```
const searchRefOffers = firebase.database().ref('searches/' + this.Store.SearchStore.searchId + '/FlightOffers')

searchRefOffers.orderByChild("PricingOptions/Price").limitToFirst(100).on("value", (snapshot) => {
                firesnap = snapshot.val()
                writeFirebaseOffersToStore(firesnap)
            })
```

My console keeps saying:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "PricingOptions/Price" at /searches/-KxoEfnwgJtMxzuIY2FJ/FlightOffers to your security rules for better performance.
```

I use the following rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "searches": {
            "$searchesid": {
                "FlightOffers": {
                    "$FlightOffersid": {
                        "PricingOptions": {
                            "0": {
                                ".indexOn": [
                                    "Price"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me out? Thank a lot!!

Comment: Nobody? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using orderByChild() then use $uid

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
      "searches": {
          "$uid": {
              "FlightOffers": {
                  "$uid": {
                      "PricingOptions": {
                              ".indexOn": ["Price"]
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Use Uid for me this way worked if you are fetching orderByValue() then use

```
{
  "rules": {
  "scores": {
     ".indexOn": ".value"
      }
  }
}
```